# Fewer options in System DSN than generally have

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, jdbc, odbc, datasource

I got some problems while creating Jdbc connection with Microsoft Access.

First I go to control panel -> click on the Administrative Tools. Then  I got this window which shown in the picture.
[image]

I click on ODBC Data Source(64 bit). Then I got this window

[image]

Now I go to the System DSN tab

[image]

Now I got SQL server. But as per [this video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhuafZrlWq4) I should get some more options. Therefore I cannot understand why I couldn't get those options. I need `Microsoft Access dBase Driver` to generate a MS Access DataBase.

My System Configuration is as per this picture below

[image]

I am using MS Office 2019.

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: The old "Jet" drivers for Access .mdb only appear in the 32-bit ODBC Administrator because they are only available to 32-bit applications. With a fresh install of Windows the only driver to appear in the 64-bit ODBC Administrator is the (rather old) "SQL Server" driver.

Comment: How could I overcome from this problem? Any alternative for ubuntu?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc

Comment: Thank you. I am using IntelliJ Idea. `Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D://tutorial/Database2.accdb");
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            s.executeQuery("select * from Student");
            ResultSet rset = s.getResultSet();` Student is the name of the table that created on Database2. Now I don't get any error but I it doesnot show me the data that are in the student table.

Comment: You can't use ODBC from recent Java versions (Java 8 and higher), so you should be looking at a different solution anyway.